# Azure Data Factory- Bigquery connector adds unnecessary characters to nested data

Tags: google-bigquery, azure-data-factory

I need to transfer BigQueryTables to Azure Blob Storage whereas BigQuery connector in ADF adds wierd "v" and curly brackets ({}) when previewing the data. For reference I am attaching a picture. Any idea what conversion is being done ? or the ADF connector is faulty ?

[image: Google-Analytics Data in ADF]

the column totals look like as follows in bigquery table :

[image: BigQuery Table in GCP]

Datasource : BigQuery

Tool : Azure Datafactory

Destination : Azure Blob Storage.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the Azure Data Factory connector for Google BigQuery needs a bit extra help in the source query to BigQuery.

If you use the following example:

```
select TO_JSON_STRING(items) as jsondata FROM ...
```

the result will contain the proper names instead of the "v" names.

Comment: Do you have a more detailed example? If I use this, it removes the first 3 column names SELECT
 [event_date]
      ,[event_timestamp]
      ,[event_name]
      ,TO_JSON_STRING([privacy_info])
FROM

Comment: @DC07, I am unaware of the solution above but I have setup a pipeline to transfer data from BQ-Tables to GoogleCloudStorage and then transfer the data to Blob-storage. Involves some additional steps but keeps the structure aligned.